# How to open my salesforce org from facebook?

Tags: integration, grant-login-access

I have to make a POC to make me able to login to my salesforce org(for ex. developer org) from a button/link or anything from my facebook home page..
Is this use case really possible??
If yes. can anyone please help me with the details about it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to do this, you need to do the following

1. Set up a Facebook application, making Salesforce the application domain.
2. Define a Facebook authentication provider in your Salesforce organization.
3. Update your Facebook application to use the Callback URL generated by Salesforce as the Facebook Website Site URL.
4. Test the connection.

[This](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/01/social-single-sign-on-authentication-providers-in-spring-12.html) tutorial from Pat Patterson (aka MetaDaddy) explains all these steps in detail. You may also find [this](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_facebook.htm&language=en_US) link useful.

Comment: Thanx Gaurav.. Good informative links. Will start to work on the POC now.  :)